# Safe traversal in Scala with better complexity

Tags: scala

I have implemented the "Safe Traversal" algorithm in Scala with the complexity of **O(n)** but I am not able to come up with a solution of better complexity. Was wondering if anyone could propose a solution with a way better time complexity. TIA.

## Safe Traversal

- The Program should take a input string of characters 'S' and 'U' where 'S' stands for Safe, 'U' stands for Unsafe. The first character is always an `S` and that is the position from where traversal begins. The objective is to write a program to move from the first `S` to the end of the array without ever stepping into a `U` (Unsafe) block. When it finishes, the program should tell if a safe traversal from left to right is possible at all or not for the given array. To make the traversal, the program has to use a jump-size. Initial jump-size should be 1 (so that one can move only one block at a time). But the jump-size can be increased or decreased by 1. The jump-size can never go below 1 and cannot be incremented/decremented from current size by more than 1.
- For sequence, 'SSUSSUSUUS', the steps would be:

  - program starts at the left-most end with initial position 1 of S with jump-size of 1
  - program finds that the next block is a S and so does not increase the jump-size and traverses to position 2
  - program finds that the next block is a U and so increases the jump-size to 2 and moves to position 4
  - program finds that with jump-size of 2 the block in position 6 is unsafe. So it decreases the jump-size to 1 and traverses to position 5
  - program finds that block in position 6 is unsafe and so increases the jump-size to 2 and traverses to position 7
  - program finds that block in position 9 is unsafe, also finds that block in position 8 is unsafe (so decreasing jump-size will not help), so increases the jump-size to 3 and traverses to position 10. Since we have hit the end of array the program returns saying safe-traversal-possible for the given sequence.

## My Solution

```
class SafeTraversal {

  def isTraversalSafe(str: String): Boolean = {

    def compute(jump: Int, ls: List[Char]): List[Char] = ls match {
      case Nil      => Nil
      case x :: Nil => List(x)

      case x :: xs => xs.drop(jump - 1).head match {
        case SafeTraversal.SAFE => compute(jump, xs.drop(jump - 1))
        case SafeTraversal.UNSAFE => {
          if (jump > 1) {
            if (xs.drop(jump - 2).head == SafeTraversal.SAFE) {
              compute(jump - 1, xs.drop(jump - 2))
            }
          }
          xs.drop(jump).head match {
            case SafeTraversal.SAFE   => compute(jump + 1, xs.drop(jump))
            case SafeTraversal.UNSAFE => compute(jump, Nil)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (SafeTraversal.isValidInput(str)) {
      compute(1, str.toList) match {
        case Nil => false
        case xs  => true
      }
    } else false
  }
}

object SafeTraversal {
  private final val DEFAULT = "SSUSSUSUUS";

  private final val SAFE = 'S';
  private final val UNSAFE = 'U';

  private def isValidInput(str: String): Boolean = {
    (str filter { _ != 'S' } filter { _ != 'U' }).size == 0
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val safeTraversal = new SafeTraversal()

    val str = if (args.length > 0) args(0) else DEFAULT
    val res = safeTraversal.isTraversalSafe(str)

    res match {
      case true  => println(s"""Safe traversal is possible for string "$str"!""")
      case false => println(s"""Safe traversal is not possible for string "$str"!""")
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: what makes you think there is a sub-linear solution here?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by that! What's sublinear?

Comment: O(n) is "ilnear". Better than O(n) is sublinear

Comment: First of all, your program has several obvious bugs. Try running it with `SUSS`. Even if you fix the bugs, the algorithm itself is wrong. You are using a greedy algorithm and one counterexample to it is `SUSUUSUUSS`. A basic algorithm for this problem is an O(n²) dynamic programming in the current position and jump size. And actually I'm not sure, if it's possible to improve the O(n²) complexity.

Comment: @kolmar Thanks for pointing out the obvious bug!
> Could you please elaborate on how is this solution greedy?
> What would be the dynamic approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Consider the example when at some position you can either keep, increase or decrease the jump size. Which one should you choose? You can't decide greedily at that moment. If you program prefers to do one of those, and never reconsiders, then it's always possible to find a counterexample. In general, you should try all three and see if one of them works in the very end. The naïve approach to this is exponential, and both dynamic programming and memoization are techniques to make it polynomial. There are quite a few questions on SO or articles in the Internet on those concepts.